# How to Create a Trigger in SQL Server to Update Cascade When @@RowCount > 1?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, trigger

I Have 2 Table

```
Table1
 | column name | type        |
 |-------------+-------------|
 | ID1         | Int         |
 | Name        | NVARCHAR(50)|


Table2
 | column name | type        |
 |-------------+-------------|
 | ID1         | Int         |
 | ID          | Int         |
 | Name        | NVARCHAR(50)|
```

I want to create a relation in Table1.ID1 And Table2.ID1 with TRIGGER For Cascade UPDATE that support the bellow T-Sql:

**Update Table1 Set ID1 = ID1 + 1**

How To create a trigger to cascade on update where the updated row count is more than 1?

(@@RowCount > 1)

Comment: Your question is not clear, however, it is usually a bad idea to update a primary key. I guess you have a conceptual problem in your table design. Give a detailed description with a case where such an update is required.

Answer (score 0):

I Found it!
this is available with use CURSOR!
I write a code that slove the problem:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[EditUserUNameTrigger]
   ON  [dbo].[User]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF(NOT UPDATE(UName))
        RETURN

    DECLARE @Old NVARCHAR(250)
    DECLARE @New NVARCHAR(250)
    DECLARE @DEL CURSOR
    DECLARE @INS CURSOR

    SET @DEL = CURSOR FOR SELECT UName FROM DELETED
    SET @INS = CURSOR FOR SELECT UName FROM INSERTED 

    OPEN @DEL
    OPEN @INS

    WHILE 1 = 1
    BEGIN
        FETCH NEXT FROM @DEL INTO @Old
        FETCH NEXT FROM @INS INTO @New

        IF(@@FETCH_STATUS <> 0)
            BREAK

        UPDATE [DesktopLayout] SET UName = @New WHERE [DesktopLayout].UName = @Old 
    END

    CLOSE @DEL
    CLOSE @INS

    DEALLOCATE @DEL
    DEALLOCATE @INS
END
```

Comment: This may generate duplicate keys.